# Making a vertical-split page responsive

Tags: html, css, split, responsive, css-tables

I have a page layout that I would like to make responsive. The page is currently split 50/50 down the middle vertically. I achieved this by making the Section div display as a table and the divs inside as cells. I also have an absolute positioned Title at the top-center of the page.

I would like to make is such that when the page is viewed on a smaller screen (e.g. tablet or mobile) the 50/50 split becomes horizontal, with all of the contained text centered horizontally and vertically, and with the Title remaining at the top-center of the page.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body,
section,
div {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Cinzel, serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
.logo {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.left-half {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}
.right-half {
  background: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <header class="logo">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="left-half cell">
      <h1>First Half</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right-half cell">
      <h1>Second Half</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: your question is not very clear. But guess what you are looking for is `media` queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries for smaller screens in which you change `display: table`and `display: table-cell` to `display: block` in `.container` and  `.cell`.

And definitely erase that `div { width: 50%; }` rule - that affects ALL divs, which you certainly won't want! (Write that 50% width into the `.cell` rule instead, and add a media query rule for it for smaller sizes that makes it 100%.